# How to update Database SQL-Server when updating Excel file in certain path using watch dog

Tags: python, sql-server, xlsx, python-watchdog

I am trying to update a Database `sql-server` based on updating `xlsx` file....

For Example Ihave an `xlsx` a sheet Called `LTE Details` file with certain Sheet like the below picture:
 [image]

As I am using watch dog to Observe the excel file in the file path

and here's my `watchdog` code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy
import sys
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import time
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# connect db
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://WWX542337CDCD\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()

class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print("EVENT")
        print(event.event_type)
        print(event.src_path)
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'

    event_handler = EventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()

# reading and insert one file at a time
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    # only process excels files
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
    if extension == 'xlsx':
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.abspath(file))
        df.to_sql(file_basename, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

so For example I add another row in this Excel Sheet `LTE Details` like in the below picture:

[image]

as When I am Observing the Run time:

I want to use this Event as the below one:

```
EVENT
modified
.\MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027.xlsx

EVENT
modified
.\A4F00FD3.tmp
```

as My Database looks like the below image using SQL-Server

[image]

So any one have any Idea how to do this?

Comment: So you're replicated changes in an Excel file to a SQL Server table? That sounds like far more trouble that it's worth. you could be far better off with an application that uses SQL Server as the back end; not a replication of the data in an Excel file. You'll be able to have multiple people edit different rows (as only one person can open the file), and won't have problems of the replication failing, and the data differing.

Comment: @Larnu actually this excel file is every day replacing by the old one getting from a Certain Server, as this excel file is the same format, but it replaced with the new add.... So all I need to add this new  data to the database when added to the excel file

Comment: Yes, you're replicating the data; and why my opinion of trying to do this is just a bad idea.

Comment: @Larnu so could you gimme a good idea for this, I just want to Observe a certain file in a specific path folder that every day is replacing with the new data, so I want to add this new data to the database automated :)... by the way I am not replacing the data I am adding the new data

Comment: *"so could you gimme a good idea for this"*... "you could be far better off with an application that uses SQL Server as the back end; not a replication of the data in an Excel file."

Comment: @Larnu but the main data is in the excel file which comes form the server and this database is based on the excel file

Comment: @Larnu  as I am pushing this data to sql by using `to_sql` and `Pandas`, Note that I just need to create a new Database for this excel, by every day updating this database based on the updates of the excel file.....
I can post my other code which push the data to sql if you need this